# Which principle is being violated?

Tags: single-responsibility-principle

I am not good at naming, I good at feeling.

Suppose we have this hypothetical function:

```
function computePowerAndPrintResult(int x){
  print(x*x);
}
```

It screams already in the naming of the function (**"And"**) that something wrong here and personally I never write code like this.
Which principle is being violated here? Is it the single-responsibility principle?

Comment: maybe you can use inbuilt library function, such as `pow` in python and `Math.pow()` in javascript
Now, to your question, you can just use `pow`

Answer (score 3):

Yes. The name is indeed a giveaway. In violation of the *single* responsibility principle, the function is responsible for two things: computing the square, and printing the result.

Also good naming sense is being violated: at the very least it should be called `computeSquareAndPrintResult` because `Power` without specifying the exponent doesn't make much sense. I'd personally call it `printSquareOf` so you can call it like `printSquareOf(x)`, which reads very naturally.

Answer (score 1):

No it's not. The single responsibility refers to a class. When a class is doing too much then it is violated. When a function is doing to much though you need to break it down.

Now I'm not saying that it's not an indication that it does.

In my mind, you need a class to compute the power, and a class that will manage the printing.

BUT: Assume that I have a need to implement an API that I would call and it would return the PDF of the compute power. I would need an api that would both calculate and print the result.

I would then create the `GetSquareValueOutput` which would have the single responsibility to orchestrate getting the data from the `SquareValueCalculator` class and then print with the `Printer` class.

This last `GetSquareValueOutput` might as well be called `computePowerAndPrintResult` and it would not break a thing. I wouldn't choose the name as it hints at a code smell, but in the end it's just a matter of context.

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR: Change the name to `printSquare`. Then the name is much shorter, is equally accurate at describing what you do, and yet... if you really want worry about the single responsibility principle, you're still breaking it. Which says more about how SRP can easily be overzealously applied, than this being a bad method.

### In depth on that name

'computePower' is a bad name for two reasons:

1. 'Power' is a binary operation (X to the Yth power) and you're not really doing that; you've locking Y to '2', and that operation has a common name too: 'square'.
2. 'compute' is usually superfluous. square already implies that calculation is going on. Look at e.g. java's AtomicInteger or BigInteger which have methods named `add` (really, in the case of BI, should be `plus`), but the point is, it's not `computePlus`. Note that it depends on a few factors; for example, in java it is common to start property getters with `get`, in a class that has an unrelated property or otherwise `square` is not as clear as one would like (say, its geometrically related, so `square` could be misunderstood to refer to the shape instead of the mathematical operation), then this is oversimplifying matters as well.

That means that part of the method name ought to be `square` and not `computePower`.

Then we have the `andPrintResult` part. Here `Result` is superfluous. What else would it be printing, other than the result?

You have 2 options:

1. This method should be named `square` and should return that value and not print anything. Make another method to print things.
2. 'and' being a code smell is.. eh. Maybe. Look, you could name this method `printSquare` which is short, clear, and contains no `and`, and yet, it's just as much of a violation of the rule as `computePowerAndPrintResults`.

In many ways `printSquare` is a straight violation of SRP, but if you change the name to `reportSquare`, and the code will compute the square and then report it to the configured (injected via dependency injection for example) 'reporter output stream', all of a sudden it's not a violation of SRP, but all we did was redefine some words, the code remained the same.